# whitelist api endpoint based on host or domain

Tags: server

I'm building an endpoint which returns images. I want to only allow requests from the same domain for this endpoint so that other people won't have access to it. I can't use CORS because you can essentially make the call inside an image tag and bypass any cors restrictions. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to prevent simple hotlinking, you can do a referrer check: Check the `Referer` *[sic!]* header, make sure it contains a whitelisted domain.

Keep in mind that the `Referer` header is sometimes missing, e.g. because it has been removed by security software concerned about the user’s privacy.

Also, it is needless to say that referrer-based checks are easily circumvented by anybody who is determined to abuse your service.

Although you cannot (as far as I know) forge the referrer in a browser request (e.g. to download the image with AJAX), you could simply set up a proxy server which would download the images with a forged referrer header and deliver them to the actual client.

But, at least, it would take some energy to do so, and you could easily block such a server by IP address (unless it's a pool of IP addresses).